# Filtering SharePoint list by current month

Tags: sharepoint, filtering

I didn't found some similar question for my problem, so I would be much grateful if someone help me.

I have SharePoint List with couple of different of type columns ( number, date time, text,look up etc).

Columns that will be used for filtering:

Month Started ( number that represent the month when the item was created - **number field** - example: 1,2,3..12 )
Today's Date  ( represent the current date as **date field (date only)** - example: 10/1/2014 )

So, my question is ,how can I take the month from the Today's Date column , represent as a number and use for filtering the Month Started column.

If the question is not understandable please write a comment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a calculated column to extract the month. This is how I do it:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Submitted Date]),"TBD",CHOOSE(MONTH([Submitted Date]),"01. January","02. February","03.  March","03. April","05.
May","06. June","07. July","08. August","09. September","10.
October","11. November","12. December"))
```

Comment: I dont know from whom is really answered this question , or its the same user but I'm really thankful for your help!! It's working!
You saved me a lot of time of searching and trying!Thanks again!